# maintaining checkpoints using Unix shell script

Tags: unix, hive

The following code does not work very effectively when it comes to managing the checkpoints. Can some give some  better idea?

```
MainScriptName="MainScriptName-"
Checkpoints="$MAIN/Checkpoints"
StepNo="02"
StepName="MyStepName"
MainLogPathFilename="$LogPath$MainScriptName$LogFilenamets.csv"

fileCount=0
fileCount=`find $Checkpoints -maxdepth 1 -name "$MainScriptName$StepNo.lck" | wc -l`
SECONDS=0
executions_status=""
StepStarted="$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')"
echo "Step No : $StepNo $StepStarted"
if [ $fileCount -eq 0 ] 
then

    $hivef $MAIN/MyscriptName/Date.hql  >> $LogPath/$MainScriptName.log 2>&1 

    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] 
    then 
        duration=$SECONDS
        echo "$StepName, $StepStarted, $StepCompleted, $(($duration / 60)), Failed" >> $MainLogPathFilename
        echo "Failed !"
        exit 10
    else 
        touch $Checkpoints/$MainScriptName$StepNo.lck
        executions_status="Success"

    fi


else
    executions_status="Skipped"

fi
    echo "$executions_status"
    StepCompleted="$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')"
    duration=$SECONDS
    echo "$StepNo, $StepName, $StepStarted, $StepCompleted, $(($duration / 60)), $executions_status" >> $MainLogPathFilename
```

and then simply read it if exists then skip it.

Comment: `touch` just means that you modify the last modification date of the file (or create it if it doesn't exist). What exactly do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: i want to decide either i have to skip or execute a process.

Comment: **1** Put your code in shellcheck.net to fix some issues with the code.  **2** lots of undefined variables in the posted code.  **3** Please provide a [mcve], as it stands, we have no idea what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "Script Name : " $MainScriptName "- Started"
StepNo="01"
fileCount=0
fileCount=`find $Checkpoints -maxdepth 1 -name "$MainScriptName$StepNo.lck" | wc -l`
StepName="Build_Report"
SECONDS=0
executions_status=""
StepStarted="$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')"

echo "File Count : $fileCount"
echo "Step No : $StepNo $StepStarted"
if [ $fileCount -eq 0 ] then

    $hivef $HDP_MAIN/CODE/TXN/HiveQuery.hql > $LogPath/$MainScriptName.log 2>&1
    query1result=$?
    ScriptError="-1" 
        ScriptError=`cat "$LogPath/$MainScriptName.log" | grep "(No such file or directory)\|Error opening session" | wc -l` 
    if [ $query1result -ne 0 ] || [ $ScriptError -gt 0 ]
    then 
        duration=$SECONDS
        echo "$StepName, $StepStarted, $StepCompleted, $(($duration / 60)), Failed" >> $MainLogPathFilename
        echo "Failed !"
        exit 10
    else 
        touch $Checkpoints/$MainScriptName$StepNo.lck
        executions_status="Successfully Completed."

    fi
else
    executions_status="Skipped"

fi
    echo "$executions_status"
    StepCompleted="$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')"
    duration=$SECONDS
    echo "$StepNo, $StepName, $StepStarted, $StepCompleted, $(($duration / 60)), $executions_status" >> $MainLogPathFilename
```